# ruby selenium-webdriver quit before exception is rescued

Tags: ruby, selenium

Recently, I am working on mobile automation using appium+selenium in ruby. But stopped by the following issue: selenium driver is quit automatically (mobile app is closed) every time an exception happens. This will result in that the following code to access the driver will fail after I manage to rescue the exception.
e.g.

```
begin
    @driver.find_element(:xpath, "//window[1]/button[27]")
rescue
    @driver.find_element(:xpath, "//window[1]/navigationBar[1]/button[2]").click
end
```

Does anyone have this issue as well?

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/exceptions_rdoc.html "By default StandardError and its subclasses are rescued. You can rescue a specific set of exception classes (and their subclasses) by listing them after rescue:

```
begin
  # ...
rescue ArgumentError, NameError
  # handle ArgumentError or NameError
end
```

I assume you are waiting for something like `ElementNotVisibleException`. So, add type of exception after `rescue`. Something like `rescue ElementNotVisibleException`.